# R routine always samples from last row of array instead of random rows

Tags: arrays, r

I have been debugging the following routine for some time.

A problem that came to my attention is that sampling is always done on the last row of my array every time I run the simulation. I want it to select rows at random each time the code is run.

Here's what I have:

```
N <- 10 

Hstar <- 5  

perms <- 10 ### How many permutations are we considering

specs <- 1:N
```

#### Set up a container to hold the identity of each individual from each permutation

```
pop <- array(dim = c(perms, N))

haps <- as.character(1:Hstar)
```

#### Assign probabilities

```
probs <- rep(1/Hstar, Hstar)
```

#### Generate permutations

```
for(i in 1:perms){
    pop[i, ] <- sample(haps, size = N, replace = TRUE, prob = probs)
}
```

#### Make a matrix to hold the 1:N individuals from each permutation

```
HAC.mat <- array(dim = c(perms, N))

for(j in specs){
    for(i in 1:perms){
        ind.index <- sample(specs, size = j, replace = FALSE) ## which individuals will we sample
        hap.plot <- pop[i, ind.index]   ## pull those individuals from a permutation
        HAC.mat[i, j] <- length(unique(hap.plot))  ## how many haplotypes did we get for a given sampling intensity (j) from each ### permutation (i)
    }
}
```

When I look at ind.index and hap.plot, I notice that values from haps are always taken from the last row in the pop variable and I can quite understand why this is occurring. I would like it to randomly sample from a given row in pop.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround that looks like it works.

```
hap.plot <- pop[sample(nrow(pop), size = 1, replace = TRUE), ]
```